# Why can't I access directly in vector iterator?

Tags: c++

Why can't i do like this? In the below code, I can access from for loop, but not from outside loop?

```
class root
{
    string name;

public:

    root()
    {
    }

    root(const string& okay)
    {
        name = okay;
    }

    void setRoot(const string& okay)
    {
        name = okay;
    }

    string getRoot()
    {
        return name;
    }

    ~root ()
    {
    }
}; // class root

int main()
{
    string a;
    vector<root> Root;
    vector<root>::iterator oley;
    root okay;

    for (int i=0; i<5;i++)   //this is to add strings in vector
    {
        cin >> a;
        okay.setRoot(a);
        Root.push_back(okay);
    }

    for (oley=Root.begin(); oley!=Root.end(); oley++)   //this is to print vectors in scren
    {
        cout << (*oley).getRoot() << endl;
    }
    oley = Root.begin();
    cout << (*oley + 2).getRoot();   //this is error. What is required to make it legal?

    return 0;
}
```

So, if we can access iterator from for loop, why can't we do so in non-looped codes?

```
cout << (*oley + 2).getRoot();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `*oley+2` is interpreted as `(*oley) + 2` which is becomes `root + 2`

update

```
cout<<(*oley+2).getRoot();
```

to

```
cout<<(*(oley+2)).getRoot();
```

or

```
cout<<oley[2].getRoot();
```

Comment: @Rockink because of operator precedence